# vba filter multiple target.address

Tags: excel, vba

I have two data tables and have vba code that filters both tables based on the chosen cell value from my two dropdown lists. However, at the moment my code only works for dropdown list 1. If I use dropdown list 2 nothing happens until I also choose something from dropdown list 1.

I want the filters to work both ways and think it has something to do with my target.address only being set to D16 where my dropdown list 1 is placed. Dropdown list 2 is placed at H16. I have tried using the operator "AND" so the code looked like this: `Target.Address = "$D$16"` AND `Target.Address = "$H$16"`. It ended with an error.

Hope you can help and thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$16" Then
        If Range("D16") = "All" Then
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
        Else
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("D16")
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("H16")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this? The precise actions may not be quite right but hopefully you get the idea.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$16" Then
    If Target.Value = "All" Then
       ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
       ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
    Else
       ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    End If
ElseIf Target.Address = "$H$16" Then
    If Target.Value = "All" Then
       ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
       ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
    Else
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    End If
End If

End Sub
```